# How do I pass a value to a method that calls a new page in the Controller class of the method?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a pane with 10 films, and every time the user clicks on a film thumbnail, I have a method that will take the user to a tickets page where they can select how many tickets they'd like to buy. However, I'm trying to figure out how to pass the Film object `loadTicketPage` in the Controller class for the called tickets page, when I call the film object from the movie page Controller.

```
public class controller {
    public void initialize() {
        film1.setImage(getFilmFromList(0).getThumbnail());
        film2.setImage(getFilmFromList(1).getThumbnail());
        film3.setImage(getFilmFromList(2).getThumbnail());
        film4.setImage(getFilmFromList(3).getThumbnail());
        film5.setImage(getFilmFromList(4).getThumbnail());
        film6.setImage(getFilmFromList(5).getThumbnail());
        film7.setImage(getFilmFromList(6).getThumbnail());
        film8.setImage(getFilmFromList(7).getThumbnail());
        film9.setImage(getFilmFromList(8).getThumbnail());
        film10.setImage(getFilmFromList(9).getThumbnail());

    }

    public void loadTicketPage(Film film) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ticketsPage.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = new Stage();

            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Ticket Page");
            stage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void film1() {
        Double price = getFilmFromList(0).getPrice();
        String title = getFilmFromList(0).getFilmName();
        loadTicketPage(getFilmFromList(0));

    }

    public void film2() {
        Double price = getFilmFromList(1).getPrice();
        String title = getFilmFromList(1).getFilmName();
        loadTicketPage(getFilmFromList(1));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TicketsPageController {
    public Label filmName;
    public Label filmDescription;

    public void initialize() {
        filmName.setText(film.getFilmTitle)
    }
}
```

Here is fxml file for the ticketsPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.SepiaTone?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="670.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: maroon;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.TicketsPageController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="lblHello" layoutX="308.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="460.0" text="Hello! Welcome to Cinema Enterpriso" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true">
         <font>
            <Font name="Broadway" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="141.0" fitWidth="297.0" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@images/University_of_Huddersfield_logo.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button fx:id="btnOpenLogin" layoutX="770.0" layoutY="46.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnOpenLoginClick" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Login">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnSignUp" layoutX="840.0" layoutY="46.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnCreateNewUser" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Sign Up">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnBasket" layoutX="925.0" layoutY="46.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnOpenOrderSummary" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Basket">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="328.0" text="Please select your tickets:" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Broadway" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ComboBox fx:id="ticketType1" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="383.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Ticket type" style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="Adult"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Child"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Teen"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Student"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Senior"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="ticketType2" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="437.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Ticket type" style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="Adult"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Child"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Teen"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Student"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Senior"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="ticketType3" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="489.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Ticket type" style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="Adult"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Child"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Teen"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Student"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Senior"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="ticketType4" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="541.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Ticket type" style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="Adult"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Child"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Teen"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Student"> </String>
               <String fx:value="Senior"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="ticketType5" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="592.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Ticket type" style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
          <items>
              <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                  <String fx:value="Adult"> </String>
                  <String fx:value="Child"> </String>
                  <String fx:value="Teen"> </String>
                  <String fx:value="Student"> </String>
                  <String fx:value="Senior"> </String>
              </FXCollections>
          </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="no1" layoutX="218.0" layoutY="383.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="no." style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="1"> </String>
               <String fx:value="2"> </String>
               <String fx:value="3"> </String>
               <String fx:value="4"> </String>
               <String fx:value="5"> </String>
               <String fx:value="6"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="no2" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="435.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="no." style="-fx-background-color: tan;">

         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="1"> </String>
               <String fx:value="2"> </String>
               <String fx:value="3"> </String>
               <String fx:value="4"> </String>
               <String fx:value="5"> </String>
               <String fx:value="6"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="no3" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="488.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="no." style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="1"> </String>
               <String fx:value="2"> </String>
               <String fx:value="3"> </String>
               <String fx:value="4"> </String>
               <String fx:value="5"> </String>
               <String fx:value="6"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="no4" layoutX="218.0" layoutY="542.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="no." style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="1"> </String>
               <String fx:value="2"> </String>
               <String fx:value="3"> </String>
               <String fx:value="4"> </String>
               <String fx:value="5"> </String>
               <String fx:value="6"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <ComboBox fx:id="no5" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="594.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="79.0" promptText="no." style="-fx-background-color: tan;">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="1"> </String>
               <String fx:value="2"> </String>
               <String fx:value="3"> </String>
               <String fx:value="4"> </String>
               <String fx:value="5"> </String>
               <String fx:value="6"> </String>
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <Label fx:id="filmName" layoutX="521.0" layoutY="123.0" text="Film" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Broadway" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="filmDescription" layoutX="485.0" layoutY="189.0" text="Description" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Broadway" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btnAddToOrder1" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="383.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnAddTicketToOrder1" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Add to order" textFill="MAROON">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnAddToOrder2" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="435.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnAddTicketToOrder2" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Add to order" textFill="MAROON">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnAddToOrder3" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="489.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnAddTicketToOrder3" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Add to order" textFill="MAROON">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnAddToOrder4" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="541.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnAddTicketToOrder4" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Add to order" textFill="MAROON">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnAddToOrder5" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="595.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnAddTicketToOrder5" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Add to order" textFill="MAROON">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnBackHomepage" layoutX="485.0" layoutY="594.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnBackToHomePageClick" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="155.0" style="-fx-background-color: tan;" text="Back to Homepage" textFill="MAROON">
         <effect>
            <SepiaTone />
         </effect>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.TicketsPageController.setStuff(TicketsPageController.java:54)
    at sample.TicketsPageController.initialize(TicketsPageController.java:41)
    ... 55 more
```

Here is my TicketPageController

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TicketsPageController {
    public Label lblHello;
    public Button btnOpenLogin;
    public Button btnSignUp;
    public Button btnBasket;
    public Label filmName;
    public Label filmDescription;
    public ComboBox ticketType1;
    public ComboBox ticketType2;
    public ComboBox ticketType3;
    public ComboBox ticketType4;
    public ComboBox ticketType5;
    public ComboBox no1;
    public ComboBox no2;
    public ComboBox no3;
    public ComboBox no4;
    public ComboBox no5;
    public Button btnAddToOrder1;
    public Button btnAddToOrder2;
    public Button btnAddToOrder3;
    public Button btnAddToOrder4;
    public Button btnAddToOrder5;
    public Button btnBackHomepage;
    private String filmTitle;

    private Film film;

    public void initialize() {
          setStuff();
//        System.out.println(filmTitle);
          filmName.setText(filmTitle);
    }

//    public void setFilm(Film film) {
//        System.out.println("in set film");
//        this.film = film;
//
//    }

    public void setFilm(Film film) {
        this.film = film;
        filmName.setText(film.getFilmName());
    }

    public void setStuff() {
        System.out.println("test");
        filmTitle = film.getFilmName();
    }

    public String printFilm(){
        return film.getFilmName();
    }

    public void btnOpenLoginClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        printFilm();
    }

    public void btnCreateNewUser(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    public void btnOpenOrderSummary(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    public void btnAddTicketToOrder1(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    public void btnAddTicketToOrder2(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    public void btnAddTicketToOrder3(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    public void btnAddTicketToOrder4(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    public void btnAddTicketToOrder5(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    public void btnBackToHomePageClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Window mainWindow = btnBackHomepage.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent newRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("homepage.fxml"));
        mainWindow.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen that before, however I didn't really understand it, and I don't think it matches my question

Comment: You could add a method in your `ticketsPage` controller that accepts a `Film` object? Then, just call that method after initializing that controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the load process of the new `Pane` you can get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` and pass the film to it:

```
public void loadTicketPage(Film film){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ticketsPage.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Ticket Page");

        // get the controller and set the film
        TicketsPageController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setFilm(film);

        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Assuming your controller looks like the following:

```
public class TicketsPageController {
    private Film film;

    public Label filmName;
    public Label filmDescription;

    public void setFilm(Film film) {
        this.film = film;
        filmName.setText(film.getFilmTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Most of it seems all okay, but I'm now having a problem with my initialise method that is giving me a LoadException, I'll paste it below: 

    public void initialize() {
        filmName.setText(film.getFilmName());
    }

Comment: UPDATE: I have tested this with a button, and it printed the film name correctly. However, when I tried it in the initialize method, I received the LoadException.
My friend has experienced a similar issue, and he fixed it by making the method static, but I cannot do this as I need to call a field of the film object

Comment: @KarishmaParmar Can you please add your fxml file to your question?

Comment: @KarishmaParmar A `LoadException` usually wraps another exception, same as `ExecutionException`, `CompletionException`, and `InvocationTargetException`. You should be looking at the `Caused by:`s to see the actual error. And if you're getting an exception you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55212037/edit) to include the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/).

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp I have now edited the question with the fxml file

Comment: @Slaw I am not receiving an error with a stack trace, I'll post below what it is saying:

javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/karis/IdeaProjects/CinemaEnterpriso/out/production/CinemaEnterpriso/sample/ticketsPage.fxml

Comment: @KarishmaParmar That looks like the `Throwable#toString()` output. For instance, in your `loadTicketPage` method you have `System.out.println(e)`. You should instead use `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: @Slaw thank you! I have tried that and the error now is stating is:

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 

and

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @KarishmaParmar can you please add the __complete stacktrace__ to your question?

Comment: @KarishmaParmar I also updated my question, maybe you want to try that again. Another thing I recognized is that the name of the controller you are referencing in your fxml (`fx:controller="sample.TicketsPage"`) is different than the name of the controller you are trying to pass the film to (`TicketsPageController`). Maybe you are using the wrong controller on one place and this is causing the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp I have added the stack trace to my question, is that the right thing? And sorry I refactored the name of my controller but forgot to update the question on here, I've now changed the question, however I'm still receiving the error

Comment: The problem is, that the `initialize` method is called before `setFilm` is called so `film` is null, which causes the error. Try setting the label text in the `setFilm` method, like I did in my updated question.

Comment: Can you please share the full code or your `TicketsPageController` where the exception happens?

Comment: My full program should be available on the link, please would you be able to have a look on there, as I am really struggling?

Comment: No there is not, please edit your question.

Comment: Okay, I have added the TicketPageController to my question

Comment: The problem is the same thing I mentioned before: `initialize()` is called before `setFilm()`. In the `initialize()` method you are calling `setStuff()` which tries to set `filmTitle = film.getFilmName();`. At this moment `film` is null, which causes the exception. Remove the `setStuff()` statement in your `initialize()` method and it should work.